# Is `extern` keyword is optional in c99 standards?

Tags: c, error-handling, output, keyword, extern

The first file is

```
/* OTHER.C */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i=35;
int fun1()
{
    i++;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
int fun2()
{
    i--;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

The second file is

```
/* MAIN.C */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "other.c"

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",i);//WORKING FINE EVEN WITHOUT THE USE OF extern int i;

    fun1();//working fine

    fun2();//working fine

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

After `#include "other.c"` in `main.c` , variable `i` along with `fun1()` and `fun2()` is working fine even without declaring it in `main.c` as `extern int i` and `extern int fun1()` and `extern int fun2()`.

But in old compilers like `turbo c`, it shows error `undeclared variable i`.

So is this a additional feature added by `C99` standards?

Comment: Since you're including `other.c` into `main.c` it's as if you have one large `main.c` file, so there's no need for an `extern` declaration of `i`.  `i` is declared and defined in `main.c`.  I'm not sure why Turbo C is complaining - maybe you're not really doing the same thing.  As a side note, Turbo C is really obsolete; you shouldn't bother with it if at all possible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: but what I am asking is whether `extern` is optional in c99 standards

Comment: It's not optional in C99.  There are times when you need to use it.  But there are also times when you don't need to use it, but no harm is done if you do.  That's the way it's always been in C (it's not new with C99). In your example, it's not needed and Turbo C shouldn't complain about it - which is why I'm guessing that you're doing something different with Turbo C that you describe here.

Comment: This question makes me thinking. If I use `i` without declaration it is an error. `int main() { printf("%p", i); }`. However, if I 'invoke' it first, it is not. `int main() {i(); printf("%p", i); }`. Why?

Comment: @Marian: because in your second case, when control reaches `printf()` then the compiler knows that there is some variable `i` as you have invoked it ,which is not the case in your first example

Comment: @Marian: in C (not C++) it's permitted by the compiler to call functions without having them declared.  This creates an implicit declaration for the function, which is why it doesn't complain when `i` is used later in the `printf()` call. It's considered poor practice today to use implicit function declarations - it makes it so the compiler can't effectively check the function call for correctness.

Comment: @Marian also in such a declaration default data type is taken to be `int`

Comment: `extern` is to variable definitions as `function prototypes` are to function definitions. You put the function protypes `void foo();` in the .h file and the definition of `void foo() { ... }` in the .c file.  Analagously for variables, you put the `extern char foo_data[];` in the .h file and `char foo_data[] = "bar";` in the .c file

Answer (score 4):

What the `#include` preprocessor directive does is to actually and physically include the file at the place of the `#include`.

The compiler proper handles what is called [*translation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), which is the output of the preprocessor after all includes and macro replacements.

All this means that the compiler doesn't see different files, it just sees one large file, which in your case contains the code from `other.c`.

The usual way to handle things like this is to make a header file, e.g. `other.h` that the main file would include, and then contains the function prototypes (declarations). Then you let the build system generate two object files, one per source file, and *link* the object files together into a single executable.

If you're using `gcc` it could most easily be done like this:

```
$ gcc main.c other.c -o myprogram
```

This tells the compiler to compile the files `main.c` and `other.c` to temporary object files, which are then linked together to create the `myprogram` executable.

For this to work you might want to make a header file that declares the needed things:

```
/* OTHER.H */
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

extern int i;
int fun1();
int fun2();

#endif
```

In the `main.c` file `#include` the header instead of the source file.

Comment: but if I remove `#include "object.c"` from `main.c` and declare `extern int i`,then compiler shows error

Comment: so when should I use `extern`

Comment: @learner When you don't `#include` the source, i.e. in the normal case.

Comment: I have done that, but I am asking that in what case `extern` has use...give me a example

Comment: @learner When a variable is *defined* in another translation unit (i.e. another source file that you don't include) you must use `extern` in the *declaration*. See e.g. the header file example in my updated answer.